# Using Pagenote package without footnotes markers

Tags: lyx, endnotes, pagenote

I'm still learning and here is what I would like to do.
I'm using the `pagenote` package in LyX and it works just fine with the ERT blocks, but I also would like to remove footnote markers from the main text (i.e. just to have the same endnotes, but without the markers in the text).
Is there a quick fix to do that?
All best
Mathias

Comment: Seems like you posted the answer below using a different account than the one you asked the question with. If you log in with the "Mathias" account you'll be able to comment on, and upvote/accept answers. Please don't post "thank you"s in answers, it will be deleted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a redefinition of the macro that prints the number might work. I.e. add

```
\renewcommand\notenumintext[1]{}
```

to the preamble after `\usepackage{pagenote}`. The code example below produces this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand\notenumintext[1]{}
\begin{document}
\section{A}

abc\pagenote{Lorem} cde\pagenote{ipsum}

\printnotes
\end{document}
```